# Написание названия документа

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Здравствуйте!
В каких случаях слова "закон", "постановление" пишутся с заглавной, а в каких - со строчной буквы?
Например, в данном случае:
"Принятый в Эстонии Закон об основной школе и гимназии дает право..."
Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слово "закон" -  нарицательное существительное, пишется со строчной буквы. Но когда входит в собственное наименование, название документа (как в Вашем примере) - то с заглавной.

Answer (score 2):

Сейчас по поводу заглавных букв вообще много достаточно противоречивых рекомендаций, я бы придерживался следующего:

Слово закон пишется с заглавной в случае если: 
~1. Далее в кавычках следует полное и точное наименование закона, как то: Закон Российской Федерации от 25 октября 1991 года N 1807-I "О языках народов Российской Федерации"; однако, если слову "закон" в названии предшествует слово федеральный (или подобное), то с заглавной пишется оно, а закон - со строчной.
~2. Либо это условно-собственное наименование ("действие Закона распространяется..."), в подобных случаях использование такого наименования обычно предваряется указанием типа "далее именуемый Закон".

Во всех остальных случаях - только со сточной. Примерно так оформлен "Закон о государственном языке Российской Федерации".

В отношении законов иностранных государств, думаю, должны применяться те же правила.
Т.е. в вашем случае либо закон со строчной, либо "Об основной школе..." в кавычках (но только если это точное название закона).

Подчеркиваю, это не более чем личное мнение.